# How to deploy nodejs web on google search console

Tags: node.js, google-search, google-search-console

I opened the server on ubuntu and applied the domain as well.

How do I get this site exposed on Google search engines?
[image]

I have added my site domain to the Google search console.

However, when I search for site: slog.website on Google, my site is not displayed.

How can I deploy on google search console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fist of all, have you add google tag for verification that you really own your website?
Go to **Settings>Ownership verification**. Here you should see a text "You are a verified owner".
[image]

If you are a verified owner then keep in mind that Google bots have to crawl and index your website. It can take some time.

Otherwise, if your are not a verified owner, scroll to Settings>Ownership verification>Additional verification methods where you can find **HTML file** or **HTML tag**.
The simplest way is to copy and paste Google HTML tag to the `<head>` of your homepage. Then deploy your website and click 'VERIFY' button.
[image]

Comment: I have already done this process. 
The problem has not been resolved yet.

Comment: I see, have you ever try URL inspection or request indexing of your page? This site explain how to use [URL Inspection Tool](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9012289#url_not_on_google)